How to schedule Expo notification if the app has been closed for a while
I'm going to use expo-notifications library to show reminder notifications. I want reminders to be displayed at a specific time (for example, 8 a.m.) but only if the app has been closed for more than 4 hours. I've already added scheduling notifications at a specific time. But I need to implement the condition above, when the app is closed or in background.
Here's my root component with implementing expo-notifications:
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import * as Device from "expo-device";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { View, Platform } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaProvider } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";

import Navigation from "./src/navigation";
import { store, persistor } from "./src/store";
import styles from "./styles";

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async () => ({
    shouldShowAlert: true,
    shouldPlaySound: false,
    shouldSetBadge: false,
  }),
});

export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded, fontError] = useFonts({
    mainReg: require("./assets/fonts/DINReg.otf"),
    mainMed: require("./assets/fonts/DINMed.otf"),
    mainBold: require("./assets/fonts/DINBold.otf"),
  });

  const [notification, setNotification] = useState<Notifications.Notification | undefined>(undefined);
  const notificationListener = useRef<Notifications.Subscription>();

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (fontsLoaded || fontError) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [fontsLoaded, fontError]);

  useEffect(() => {
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync();
    scheduleReminderNotification();

    notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener((notification) => {
      setNotification(notification);
      console.log("Notification received:", notification);
    });

    return () => {
      notificationListener.current && Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(notificationListener.current);
    };
  }, []);

  async function scheduleReminderNotification() {
    const now = new Date();
    const trigger = new Date();
    trigger.setHours(8, 0, 0); // Set to 8:00 AM local time
    if (trigger <= now) {
      trigger.setDate(trigger.getDate() + 1); // If 8:00 AM has already passed today, set for tomorrow
    }

    await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
      content: {
        title: "Reminder",
        body: "You haven't opened the app for more than 4 hours. Check out now!",
      },
      trigger,
    });
  }

  if (!fontsLoaded && !fontError) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <SafeAreaProvider>
          <View style={styles.container} onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
            <Navigation />
            <StatusBar style="auto" />
          </View>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}

async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
  let token;

  if (Platform.OS === "android") {
    await Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("default", {
      name: "default",
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
      vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      lightColor: "#FF231F7C",
    });
  }

  if (Device.isDevice) {
    const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
      const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
      finalStatus = status;
    }
    if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
      alert("Failed to get push token for push notification!");
      return;
    }
    try {
      const projectId = Constants?.expoConfig?.extra?.eas?.projectId ?? Constants?.easConfig?.projectId;
      if (!projectId) {
        throw new Error("Project ID not found");
      }
      token = (
        await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
          projectId,
        })
      ).data;
      console.log(projectId);
      console.log(token);
    } catch (e) {
      token = `${e}`;
    }
  } else {
    alert("Must use physical device for Push Notifications");
  }

  return token;
}


Use AsyncStorage to save the time when the user opened the app. Something like AsyncStorage.setItem('lastTime', JSON.parse(Date.now())). You could run it when the main component mount (the useEffect instead App component).
Then, you could use expo-task-manager (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/task-manager/) to run a task at 8PM, where you'll get the lastTime value from the AsyncStorage. If that value is higher than 4 hours, you send a local notification using Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync (check the trigger property in that function).
I would suggest you to ask for this to ChatGPT. It will give you the exact code, and even the extra configurations you need to add in app.json in order to be able to run tasks in the background (with expo-task-manager)
